# Visualization: Changing group memberships over time

Tags: classification, time-series, visualization

I am looking for an interactive visualization. I have store classification based on their sales (sales buckets) for multiple quarters. I want to visualize

1. The size of each bucket for every quarter
2. The contribution towards
   sales from each of the buckets in the previous quarter (essentially
   capturing upgrade/downgrade of stores from one bucket to the other)

I tried Sankey diagrams but the issue is that it only helps me visualize the **count** of stores moving (changing buckets) over time.

### Edit 2

[image: Sankey diagram showing movement of stores across buckets]

**The numbers in the example below and the diagram might not match**

I want to capture the contribution of sales from previous bucket to the next as well.

```
Q1 buckets|Q1 Sales  
0-5tr|1831  
5-10tr|561  
10-20tr|452  
20-50tr|400  

Q2 buckets|Q2 Sales  
0-5tr|1600  
5-10tr|200  
10-20tr|50  
20-50tr|69
```

Here, tr is an abbreviation for turnover
Similarly, I will have the number of stores in each bucket for both quarters. Although, I can visualize the movement of stores (using sankey) from one bucket to the other by creating a nXn matrix (n being the number of buckets) and each value i,j representing the number of stores moving from bucket i (in Q1) to bucket j (in Q2), I am not able to do so for its sales.

Comment: Could you provide sample data? It wiĺl make the question more clear.

Comment: can you show us what your sankey diagram looks like?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you want a [stacked area chart](https://visage.co/data-visualization-101-area-charts/).

Comment: @Emre: The stacked area chart captures only half of what I want to visualize. In addition to the change in sales of the buckets, I also want to portray the contribution of each previous bucket in the current one.
For example, if 20 stores moved from 0-5 tr bucket in Q1 to 5-10 tr bucket in Q2, I want to capture the amount of sales coming from 0-5 tr bucket into 5-10 tr bucket in Q1 and Q2 resp.

Comment: @BrandonLoudermilk: Added the diagram in the post

Comment: It seems straightforward to extend your illustration temporally. To aid legibility I would visually de-emphasize all buckets except the selected one; the image above is a mess.  I don't know of any off-the-shelf solutions, but you could probably code it up in D3: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/